# Programmatically (or optionally) override Chrome's New Tab page

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, tabs

I've written a Chrome extension that [overrides the New Tab page](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/override):

**manifest.json**:

```
  "chrome_url_overrides": {
    "newtab": "new-tab.html"
  },
```

Is there a way to make this override optional? That is, I'd like to enable the user to uncheck a checkbox in the options page and disable the New Tab override. This must be possible because when I open a new tab for the first time, there's a popup informing of an extension changing the New Tab settings and asking whether to keep changes or restore settings:

[image]

I couldn't find any API for controlling overrides. The [New Tab Redirect](https://github.com/jimschubert/NewTab-Redirect/blob/master/js/options_constants.js) project doesn't have an option to display the native New Tab.

Comment: That would most probably go against Google's single purpose policy for extensions. You either are a New Tab replacement or you aren't.

Answer (score 12):

Google made a [Star Wars new tab replacement](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/boeojddkbfhdgnnicgkgogjnbkdljibb) which allows you to view the default new tab page. The url it uses is `chrome-search://local-ntp/local-ntp.html`.

Example:

**options.html:**

```
<input type="checkbox"> Use default new tab page
```

**options.js:**

```
var checkbox = document.querySelector("input[type=checkbox]")
checkbox.addEventListener("click", function() {
 chrome.storage.sync.set({ defaultnewtab: checkbox.checked })
})
```

**newtab.js:**

```
chrome.storage.sync.get("defaultnewtab", function(storage) {
 if(storage.defaultnewtab) {
  chrome.tabs.update({ url: "chrome-search://local-ntp/local-ntp.html" })
 }
})
```

Comment: Is there a URL that will work here for a Firefox Web Extension?

Answer (score 9):

Instead of using the `chrome_url_override`  you could write a listener that listens for when tabs update using the `chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener()`, then check if the url is chrome://newtab/ and if it is and the check box is ticked, then using `chrome.tabs.update()` relocate them to another page.

Comment: This works if the [`tabs` permission is requested](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs) (which shows as a warning when installing the extension), and the [`chrome.tabs.update`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-update) will stuff the ugly-looking `chrome-extension://hibkhcnpkakjniplpfblaoikiggkopka/html/fauxbar.html` URL of the extension into the Omnibox. How can the Omnibox be cleared?

Comment: I used this exact method, but new tabs not always re-directing correctly, sometimes it hangs with the default chrome new tab page, searching for hours now, no working answer found, 
Seems like an inconsistent issue with `chrome.tabs.update`

Comment: Another problem is that the url bar is not focused by default. Any idea how to focus it?

Answer (score 8):

Using the Star Wars method as described @Daniel Herr, I did this, which is working well. Although feels a little hack-y.

I have an option being set in the `popup.html` whether the Extension is "on" or not.

First off, set the default new tab page using the Chrome defined method:

**manifest.json**

```json
"chrome_url_overrides": {
      "newtab": "newtab.html"
},
```

Then in your Extension's `newtab.html` call a new JavaScript file, `newtab.js` (or whatever).

I am also using jQuery, so my code uses that, but you can do this natively using DOMContentLoaded.

**newtab.js**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){ 

    // It takes a moment for the Chrome query/update so sometimes there is a flash of content
    // Hiding the Body makes it look blank/white until either redirected or shown
 $('body').hide();

 var background = chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage();
 var _app = background._app;

 // App is OFF, show Default New Tab
 if(!_app._on){

  // Get the current Tab
  chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true }, function(tabs) {

   var active = tabs[0].id;
          
            // Set the URL to the Local-NTP (New Tab Page)
   chrome.tabs.update(active, { url: "chrome-search://local-ntp/local-ntp.html" }, function() { });
  });

 // App is ON, show custom content
 } else {
  
  $('body').show();
 }

});
```

Basically, the methodology is to update the Tab so that it is redirected to `chrome-search://local-ntp/local-ntp.html` which is the hard URL to the default Chrome NTP.

Since this is a Chrome internal URL -- the URL field still appears blank.

Comment: The missing piece of information was the URL - since redirection to `chrome://newtab` gives nothing. Very useful answer.

Comment: seems like promising, but I believe the correct method would be the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30439347/12204242) above, though it's not working consistently, but will give this a try, thanks for the share