# Clear the Omnibox from Chrome extension code

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, omnibox

I've written a Chrome extension that replaces the new tab *if the user wants that*. It works by intercepting tabs.onUpdated and redirecting `chrome://newtab/` to another page from the extension, as described [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30437737/programmatically-or-optionally-override-chromes-new-tab-page/30439347#30439347).

The problem is that the address bar of that page keeps the (ugly) URL of the HTML within the extension, e.g. `chrome-extension://hibkhcnpkakjniplpfblaoikiggkopka/html/newtabl.html`. How can that URL be replaced with the empty string?

I've tried history.replaceState, but the best that can do is to change the file (`newtab.html`) in the path. Using an http:// URL crashes the extension:

```
history.replaceState({}, 'iDoRecall practice', 'http://type-anything-here.com');
```

Any clever way to clear the Omnibox?

Answer (score 1):

Put simply, [History API](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/browsers.html#the-history-interface) can only change the path part of the URL, not the origin (protocol://host:port) for an obvious reason of preventing site fraud:

> If the origin of the resulting absolute URL is not the same as the origin of the responsible document specified by the entry settings object, and either the path or query components of the two parsed URLs compared in the previous step differ, throw a SecurityError exception and abort these steps. (This prevents sandboxed content from spoofing other pages on the same origin.)

The omnibox may be empty only in one case: on a new tab page, that is you'll have to replace the new tab in manifest.json in [chrome_url_overrides](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/override).

Comment: The problem with overriding the new tab is that the user may not want that (e.g. they already use a new tab replacement extension, as they're getting more popular), and there's no API to selectively override the new tab.

Comment: I would use one override page but with different content depending on the user options.

Comment: @wOxxOm: the problem with using the same new tab override page but with different content is that you can't possibly know what the user had as their New tab replacement before. It's [not even recommended to try and emulate Chrome's default "top visited sites" layout](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/override#tips).

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34068126/13189727) outlines a "hacky" sort of substitute by redirecting to chrome-search://local-ntp/local-ntp.html if the user opts out.