# Defer to other new tab chrome extensions

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

We'd like to have our users be able to defer our new tab extension to another new tab extension they have installed.

I.e. Someone installs Momentum and then installs our extension but would rather have Momentum open instead of ours. (We have additional functionality). Is this possible without the user disabling / uninstalling our extension?

Comment: It really depends on what you want your extension to do.  Try to take a minimalist approach: if the website hasn't been altered from what you expect it to be, then you may be able to assume another extension isn't present.  Or use an option page to figure out if they want your extension running (but that seems to be equivalent to disabling the extension).

Comment: To answer your specific question "let user use extension X instead of Y", it's simply a question of install order. If the user reinstalls Momentum after your extension, it will take priority. However, they will lose all settings if they uninstall and in general the duplicate applies (i.e. there is no API to control it).

Comment: I found my answer but folks keep deleting it, it's basically:

You could have it so that instead of using the chrome_url_override you could write a listener that listens for when tabs update using the chrome.tabs.onUpdate.addListener(), then check if the url is chrome://newtab/ and if it is and the check box is ticked, then using chrome.tabs.update() relocate them to another page.

from this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30439347/4414229